# UIAutomation FlaUI - Detect Both Closing and Opening Windows at the Application Level

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation, flaui

I have successfully used the solution for detecting opening windows described here: [UIAutomation FlaUI - Detect opening windows on application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72486331/uiautomation-flaui-detect-opening-windows-on-application-level).

However, I would also like to also detect closing window events **in addition to** opening window events.
I duplicated the code in order to detect the second event:

```
        AutomationElement root = automation.GetDesktop();

        UIA3AutomationEventHandler automationOpenEventHandler = new UIA3AutomationEventHandler(
            root.FrameworkAutomationElement,
            automation.EventLibrary.Window.WindowOpenedEvent,
            HandleOpenEvents);

        automation.NativeAutomation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            automation.EventLibrary.Window.WindowOpenedEvent.Id,
            root.ToNative(),
            (Interop.UIAutomationClient.TreeScope)TreeScope.Descendants,
            null,
            automationOpenEventHandler);

        UIA3AutomationEventHandler automationCloseEventHandler = new UIA3AutomationEventHandler(
            root.FrameworkAutomationElement,
            automation.EventLibrary.Window.WindowClosedEvent,
            HandleCloseEvents);

        automation.NativeAutomation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            automation.EventLibrary.Window.WindowClosedEvent.Id,
            root.ToNative(),
            (Interop.UIAutomationClient.TreeScope)TreeScope.Descendants,
            null,
            automationCloseEventHandler);
```

However, only one of the two (I believe the second one declared above) actually works.
Note that if I declare just one of the handlers above, either the open or close, it works fine. I just don't know how to get both going.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The code here works fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292428/403671

Comment: Thanks, with a little modification that code worked for me.  However, I would like to know how the same can be accomplished using FlaUI.

Comment: The difference is my code adds an event to the window, not the whole tree. This FlaUI thing is just a wrapper over UI automation.